# Unable to connect to ChromeCast

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

I recently moved home and upgraded my router. It's a **ZTE router** and the model number is **ZXHN H298A**.
Since I have installed this router, I am unable to connect to Chromecast.
I did a factory reset couple of times on Chromecast and reconnected through the Google Home app. It finds and connects but then eventually says it is unable to connect. I cannot find my device when I try to cast from my phone/tablet. It just says no device found. When I go to my Google Home app, this device is listed but when I click on it, it says cannot connect.
I have looked around for this issue. A lot of suggestions are to disable Access Point Isolation. I have gone through all options on my router portal but I am unable to find it.
Has anyone come across this problem or does anyone know how to disable AP isolation on **ZTE ZXHN H298A**.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to turn off the wifi isolation (aka WIRELESS, AP OR CLIENT ISOLATION) to fix this issue.

According to the ZTE manual (Manual Source: https://hyperoptic.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/ZTE-H298A-admin-manual.pdf) you can:

1. log in your router
2. navigate to Local Network > WLAN > WLAN Basic > WLAN SSID Configuration
3. under this page, there is "WLAN SSID configuration" section, If you have more than one ssid setup, then make sure you choose the right one that your Chromecast has been connected.
4. You will find the wifi isolation on/off option, inside that "WLAN SSID configuration" section

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Pop SkY, thank you for your comment.Unfortunately I am unable to see these options when I log into portal. I just see options to configure SSID, Security and password for both bands.

Comment: @pop-sky Are you saying to turn "SSID Isolation" off or on? I feel like I tried all permutations of settings, but my chromecast still isn't connecting. I have exactly the same issue as the op described, except I do see the "SSID Isolation" switch in my WLAN settings as you described.

Comment: @kris OP wanna "disable AP isolation" which is turn off.

Comment: @MustafaSalam i'm not sure if this is the chromecast issue or the router issue. First of all, you need to make sure your chromecast has connected to the home wifi network, then other device(s) can talk to the chromecast via the same wifi. enjoy :)